# Error in the documentation MariaDB -> mysqlbinlog: `--rewrite-db` and `--database`

Tags: replication, backup, mariadb, mysqlbinlog, documentation

In the mysqlbinlog utility [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlbinlog-options/), the `--rewrite-db=name` option has the following explanation

> Filtering (e.g. with --database=name ) happens **AFTER** the database rewrites have been performed.

However, my tests show that the filtering with the `--database` option happens **BEFORE** the `--rewrite-db` option is applied.

I reproduced the issue in the following way: I created a database `db1` with a table `t1` that contains one column `c1`. Binlog format = `ROW`.

```
CREATE DATABASE db1;
use db1;
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 varchar(255));
```

Then I executed the following command:

```
FLUSH LOGS;
```

Made an insert into the table

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1) VALUES (`row in db1.t1`);
```

Executed the command again

```
FLUSH LOGS;
```

I use the command below (the `--vv` parameter decrypts the commands) to check what is extracted from the binlogs:

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000033 --rewrite-db='db1->new_db_name' --database='new_db_name' -vv
```

Only comments are output, no `INSERT` commands. However, if I specify the name `db1` in the `--database` parameter, then `INSERT` commands will be displayed:

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000033 --rewrite-db='db1->new_db_name' --database='db1' -vv
```

output:

```
...
...
BINLOG '
eI98YxMBAAAANgAAABwCAAAAADMAAAAAAAEAC25ld19kYl9uYW1lAAJ0MQABDwL8AwFyNVlH
eI98YxcBAAAAMQAAAE0CAAAAADMAAAAAAAEAAf/+DQByb3cgaW4gZGIxLnQxmq6ESw==
'/*!*/;
### INSERT INTO `new_db_name`.`t1`
### SET
###   @1='row in db1.t1' /* VARSTRING(1020) meta=1020 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
...
...
```

Thus, it turns out that `mysqlbinlog` first filters the binlog file with the `--database` parameter and only then makes replacements with the `--rewrite-db` parameter, which contradicts the documentation.

I tested similar scenarios for MySQL(no MariaDB), and it works as it should, the filtering is run **AFTER** the replacements.

Do I understand correctly that this is an error in the documentation? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code it seems `--database` [option is applied](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/1a057a923ba8e7cdf9c065624f9a24c02dcecdd2/client/mysqlbinlog.cc#L1227) to `QUERY_EVENT`/`QUERY_COMPRESSED_EVENT` [just before](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.11/client/mysqlbinlog.cc#L1238) [print_use_statement](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.11/client/mysqlbinlog.cc#L792) uses the `--rewrite-db`.

With the `TABLE_MAP_EVENT`, `--database` is [applied](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/1a057a923ba8e7cdf9c065624f9a24c02dcecdd2/client/mysqlbinlog.cc#L1408) before `--rewrite-db` is [applied](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.11/client/mysqlbinlog.cc#L1539) to `TABLE_MAP_EVENT`.

So you are absolutely right, this is a documentation error. MariaDB's KB is editable if you'd like to change this.

Comment: Thanks for the github links. Very understandable. I corrected the description in KB MariaDB. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlbinlog-options/+revision/121791/116398/